# Calculating the Min of Date from the related list

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I am having one big task and from the last 2 weeks I am working on to solve it but without any result. Please help me out to solve this puzzle.
So we are having one object Entity group, which is the collection of all the Accounts. In Accounts, we are having multiple Invoices and Now the requirement is that we have tomake 4 fields in Account and 2 in Entity group, all with the Date field.

1. First invoice = we are calculating the Min of Signing Date of all the Invoices of the Account.
2. First invoice as product client = Min of Signing date of all the invoices of the Account where Invoices have Contract and in the Contract having one field Contract service provided = which is not blank or its not 'currency account'
   4 and 5 we will see after
   Now if we go to the Entity group, we have to make another 2 fields (Date), and having one or multiple Account related lists.
3. First invoice Account group = min of the first invoices from the Accounts related list
4. First invoice as product client AG = min of the first invoice of the Accounts where contract cervice provided is not blank or 'currency account' from the Account related list.

Now if we go back to the Account object:

We still need to make another 2 fields:

1. First invoice Account group = here we should take the value from the Entity group via lookup maybe
2. First invoice as product client AG = here also we should take the value from the Entity group via lookup I guess.

If the Account dont have the Entity group selected than the First invoice Account group and first invoice as product client AG should take the value from the own Account, First invoice account group from the First invoice field and the First invoice as Product client AG from the First Invoice as Product client.

I have make one screenshot from Account

[image]

The below screenshot is from Entity group

[image]

The classes I have created are:
1. For the first invoice

```
 global class BatchCalcFirstInvoice implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable {



    String query = ' SELECT id,(SELECT Date_Invoice__c FROm Invoices__r WHERE Date_iNVOICE__C!=null ORDER BY Date_Invoice__c ASC LIMIT 1),First_Invoice__c FROM Account';


  global BatchCalcFirstInvoice() {

  }

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {  
    List<Account> toUpdate = New List <Account> ();
    for(Account A: (List<Account>) scope) {
      if(!A.Invoices__r.isEmpty()){
        A.First_Invoice__c = A.Invoices__r[0].Date_Invoice__c;
        toUpdate.add(A);
            }
            if(A.Invoices__r.isEmpty()){
                A.First_Invoice__c=null;
                toUpdate.add(A);
            }
    }
    update toUpdate;
  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

  }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) { 
        Database.executeBatch(this); 
    }

}
```

---

2. for first invoice product client

   global class BatchFirstInvoiceasProductClient implements Database.Batchable,Schedulable {

   ```
       string conServiceProvided = '%CURRENCY ACCOUNTS%';

       String query = 'SELECT Id,(SELECT id, Contract_Service_Provided__c, Date_Invoice__c From Invoices__r WHERE Contract_Service_Provided__c != null and (Not Contract_Service_Provided__c LIKE : conServiceProvided) ORDER BY Date_Invoice__c ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account';

       global BatchFirstInvoiceasProductClient() {

       }

       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
           return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
       }

       global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {  
           List<Account> toUpdate = New List <Account> ();
           for(Account A: (List<Account>) scope) {
               if(!A.Invoices__r.isEmpty()){
                   A.First_Invoice_as_Product_Client__c = A.Invoices__r[0].Date_Invoice__c;
                   toUpdate.add(A);
               }
           }
           update toUpdate;
       }
       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

       }

       global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
           BatchFirstInvoiceasProductClient batchable = new BatchFirstInvoiceasProductClient();
           Database.executeBatch(batchable, 50);
       }
   }
   ```

Now the rest of the code I am missing from entity group, please help me out how to find the min of first invoice of all the related accounts from the Entity group object.

Comment: This sounds like a very good use case for [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) with no code written.

Comment: ... subject to the relationship being master-detail, or being changed to be master-detail.

Comment: Its lookup, not master detail. and yes we do have Declarative lookup rollup installed but don't know how to use it. Once I tried but it was not working.

Comment: Now I wanted to add one Account to the Entity group but I am getting error : Apex trigger onAccount caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: onAccount: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 1 with id 006b000000IQw2uAAD; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Please check that Subscription Package, Effective Date, Contract Term and Billing Agreement are properly filled.: []: ()

Comment: @Keith C - The raison d'être for Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary is that it does support lookup relationships, in contrast to standard OOTB roll-up summary fields, which require master-detail relationships.  That's what the "Lookup" part of the name means.

Comment: Hi @MatthewSouther, My bad.